# Azure CosmosDB create SQLParameter with is_defined command

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to create SqlQuerySpec class with query text that contains:

```
is_defined (@param)
```

and I have a hard time to create the corresponding SqlParameter class with @param value. It is always represented as a string and not json document path.

example:

```
Select * 
from c .... 
where is_defined("some_json_document_path")
```

instead off:

```
Select * 
from c .... 
where is_defined(some_json_document_path)
```

Answer (score 3):

Just modify your code a little bit.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents;
using Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client;
using System;
using System.Linq;


namespace JayGongDocumentDB.module
{
    class QueryWithSqlParam
    {
        private static readonly string endpointUrl = "https://***.documents.azure.com:443/";
        private static readonly string authorizationKey = "***";
        private static readonly string databaseId = "db";
        private static readonly string collectionId = "coll";

        private static DocumentClient client;

        public static async void QueryTest()

        {
            client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(endpointUrl), authorizationKey);
            var uri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, collectionId);

            var Parameters = new SqlParameterCollection()
                                                    {
                                                        new SqlParameter("@param", "c.test")
                                                    };

            IQueryable<Pojo> queryable = client.CreateDocumentQuery<Pojo>(
                                                uri,
                                                new SqlQuerySpec
                                                {
                                                   QueryText = "SELECT c.id,c.name,c.test FROM c WHERE is_defined(" + Parameters[0].Value + ")"
                                                });

            foreach (Pojo p in queryable)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nRead {0}", p);
            }
        }
    }

    class Pojo : Document
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

}
```

Sample code:

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Jay"
    },
    {
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Bob",
        "test": []
    },
    {
        "id": "3",
        "name": "Jay"
    }
]
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this works, but you aren't using SqlParameter but a simple string concatenation and generating a dynamic query. Nevertheless thanks for your answer.

Comment: @SrdjanTrailovic I still used `SqlParameter`  function,just not in the `SqlQuerySpec` function,did i ? Great,it works for you anyway. You could mark it as answer,thanks a lot.

Comment: The goal here is to use `SqlParameter` inside  `SqlQuerySpec ` so I can prevent SQL injection, and not use a dynamic query.

Comment: @SrdjanTrailovic However, in my above code, you also just need to adjust param in SqlParameterCollection ,not modifying sql itself  in `SqlQuerySpec` everytime. The sql is not dynamic, the param is dynamic. In addition, obviously, the function encapsulated by `SqlQuerySpec` treats your incoming parameters as a string unless you modify the source code.

Comment: @SrdjanTrailovic Hi,any progress?

Comment: No, didn't found the solution yet.